# How to ignore unneccessary comment line from the input file in C

Tags: c

I want to write a code in C in order to read the the data from input file. But I want to ignore the lines starting with # and @ . I know that can be done using the fgets and continue but I can't code it .I tried to understand the answer of already asked question but I couldn't . So, I am asking my question separately.

my input file looks like this :-

```
 #random lines
 #comment                
 @comment 
 @comment

 1234   1.01  2.02   3.02
 1453   1.02  20.04  3.01
```

Here is what I wrote :-

```
 #include<stdio.h>

 int main()
 {

  FILE *fp;
  char line[1000];
  char s1[13];

  fp = fopen ("test.txt","r");

  while (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin))    

  {

   if (*line == '#') 

   continue;

   else

   sscanf(line, "%s", s1);

   }
    printf("line = %s\n", s1);
    return 0;
    }
```

I would be grateful if somebody could help me .

Thanks,

Comment: Show what you've tried.

Comment: You don't need an `else` after the `continue` since the `continue` will short-circuit the loop. But you do need to put the `printf` inside the loop. As is, the `printf` will output the last line of the file.

Comment: Hi, that I understand but do you think sscanf() line is correct. I feel something is wrong with that but since my program is not working.

Comment: The `sscanf` line will extract the first word from the input line, and assumes that the first word is 12 or fewer characters. Whether that's right or wrong depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of ways to do it, but using `fgets` you have three things to consider: (1) finding the first non-whitespace character in the line to test, (2) what to do with blank lines (it looks like you just want the data, so I've removed them) and (3) handling/removing the `'\n'` at the end of each line included by `fgets`. A very basic approach to this problem would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXS 256

int main (void)
{
    char line[MAXS] = {0};

    while (fgets (line, MAXS, stdin) != NULL) 
    {
        char *p = line;

        size_t len = strlen (line);

        while (len > 0 && (line[len-1] == '\n' || line[len-1] == '\r'))
            line[--len] = 0;    /* strip newline or carriage rtn    */


        while (isspace (*p))    /* advance to first non-whitespace  */
            p++;

        /* skip lines beginning with '#' or '@' or blank lines  */
        if (*p == '#' || *p == '@' || !*p)
            continue;

        printf ("%s\n", line);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Input**

```
$ cat dat/cmmt.dat
 #random lines
 #comment
 @comment
 @comment

 1234   1.01  2.02   3.02
 1453   1.02  20.04  3.01
```

**Use/Output**

```
$ ./fgets_skip_comment <dat/cmmt.dat
 1234   1.01  2.02   3.02
 1453   1.02  20.04  3.01
```

---

**To stop at line that begins "2106"**

What you want to do is compare the first **four characters** beginning at `p`. Now it is unclear if you want to print the line containing **2106** and then stop **--or--** stop **before** you print the line. If it is the latter, then just move the `printf` below the following test:

```
        printf ("%s\n", line);

        /* stop at line that begins with 2106 */
        if (strncmp (p, "2106", 4) == 0)
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, 
both of the answer are really helpful. I have another small query. I have some 4000 rows in my input file but I want to stop at the row which starts with an entry "2106". How do I achieve it. I thought I can achieve it by putting an if condition 
       'if( *p== "2106")
       break;'
but doesn't work , any ideas how to make it work ?

Comment: Take a look at the addition to the answer. **Note:** to stop before you print the line with **2106**, move the `printf` **below** the added `strncmp` test.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem I see is that you open the file `test.txt`, but

- fail to do any error checking (`fopen` will return `NULL` if the file isn't found)
- don't use the file pointer in the `fgets` (you're using `stdin` instead of `fp`)
- never close the file (it's good practice to `fclose(fp)` when finished with the file)

Other issues

- `s1` should be as large as `line` to avoid any possibility of buffer overflow (or you have to limit the string length in the `sscanf`).
- the code checks for `#` but not `@`
- the `else` is unnecessary since the `continue` short-circuits the loop
- the `printf` should be in the loop
- the `sscanf` extracts the first word from the line (not sure if that's what you want or not)
- you need to check the return value from `sscanf`, since `sscanf` will return `0` on a blank line

So the code should look like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXL 1000

int main( void )
{
    FILE *fp;
    char line[MAXL];
    char s1[MAXL];

    if ( (fp = fopen ("test.txt","r")) == NULL )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Unable to open file: test.txt\n" );
        exit( 1 );
    }

    while ( fgets(line, sizeof line, fp) )
    {
        if (*line == '#' || *line == '@')
            continue;

        if ( sscanf(line, "%s", s1) == 1 )
            printf("1st word on this line = '%s'\n", s1);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Next time it's better to show what you have tried with `fgets` but I'll help you out anyways so for example say

```
while (fgets(inputFile, sizeof inputFile, stdin)) {
    if (*inputFile == '#') // What action do you want it to do if it reaches a     #
}
```

Comment: You got it 1/2 right. `if (*inputFile == '#' || *inputFile == '@') continue;` And.. it is much better to use `buf` of `buffer` instead of `inputFile` as your are not reading `stdin` into an `inputFile`, but rather a character buffer.

Comment: It was an example... what happens it is is inputFile[100]

Comment: sorry for the delay. I was adjusting the code.I fscanf for most purposes but I couldn't understand fgets works.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin pretty sure he was giving an example and not the entire code